# What should I do so that when the user completes the flow, Tile in the Guided Action Component should not be grayed out and unclickable?

Tags: workflow, actions-and-recommendations

What should I do so that when the user completes the flow, the flow tile in the Guided Action & Recommendations Component should not be grayed out and unclickable?

P.S - This is a service console app and I have tried redirecting to URL and Object after the flow finishes using aura component but it did not solve the issue.

[image]